# Data structure for fast searching in C++

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, data-structures

I need to store the values like the following in a data structure,

```
id   x     y     z
0    0.1   0.1   0.1
1    0.2   0.1   0.6
2    0.01  0.3   0.1
.....
```

Now I need to match the x,y,z double values and get the corresponding id(int) value. I might need to store around 400000 values. What sot of data structure should I use for efficient searching? Does C++ come with any built-in structures that would support my requirement.

Comment: Build a `struct` (say `foo`) containing the `x`, `y`, and `z` values, and the necessary predicates,  Then use a `std::map<foo, int>`; assuming your `id` can be represented as an `int`. Searching will be O(log N). The only thing you'll have to wrangle with are floating point comparisons, but that depends on how candidate values for `x`, `y`, and `z` arise.

Comment: How are you testing for equality of `double`s? The possible answers will be much different if you use `operator==` versus something like `abs(x-y) < threshold` or something else.

Comment: It could depend on the performance you want. Do you care about the insertion time or only the search ?

Comment: You might be looking for a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), if you want "closest point" to the query (and not only the query itself, in case you don't know exactly what you are looking for, but need the closest neighbor)

Comment: The search would be more important since I would only be inserting once but searching frequently. I might have to use abs because of double values.

Comment: I believe the best option is a hash-table. Yet you have to design the hash function to have good distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't interested in NN search, you can use `std::unordered_set`. You will need to define your own hash function, however.

Here is an (probably terrible) example:

```
struct entry
{
    int id;
    double x, y, z;

    // constructor if needed, etc...
};

struct entry_hasher
{
    size_t operator()(const entry &e) const
    {
        std::hash<double> h;
        return h(e.x) ^ (h(e.y) << 1) ^ (h(e.z) << 2);
    }
};

std::unordered_set<entry, entry_hasher> entries;
```

Otherwise, the standard does not provide containers capable of geometric queries (such as NN).

Comment: What? Are you going to base your search on a hash of a floating point value, and exact equality of two floating point numbers? That's a terrible idea

Comment: OP didn't mention a requirement for a search tolerance.

Comment: With floating point numbers, it's always a requirement. (and he did, in comments).

Comment: For the purpose of exact comparison, floats are isomorphic to ints (they were designed to work in old databases that weren't FP-aware). No, it is not always a requirement: Mesh generation over FP domains requires exact arithmetic, which is accomplished by treating floats as sparse fixed point numbers (expansions).

Comment: There is no such thing as "exact" when dealing with floating point numbers, that's the point.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only to do exact search, then a hash table ([unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/)) would be a good choice. Make the key a [tuple](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/) or a struct and the value the int id.

If you need to do interval search (e.g. find the element closest to x) and you always search from x,y,z in order, then you'll need an ordered data structure. An ordered tree ([map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)) should work. Use a three levels of nested `map` so you can do search by doing essentially `mymap[x][y][z]` with whatever interval rules you want to apply.

If you need a more sophisticated search, where you can start from any elements or search where you only know the latter two elements, then you'll need a multidimensional ordered data structure, which can be used to partition the dimensions world space for logarithmic searching. Some examples are [octtree](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) or [k-d tree](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). There is no standard library implementation of an octtree/k-d tree as far as I can tell. There are many variations of this class of data structure, for example, you may use a skiplist instead of a tree.

Comment: What? Are you going to base your search on a hash of a floating point value, and exact equality of two floating point numbers? That's a terrible idea. And no, ordered tree won't simply work for interval search by more than one feature.

Comment: @amit a good hash(float, float, float) -> int with a "chained" hash to resolve collisions should do the trick. Anyway, we only want an integer "hint" to find a match quickly.

Comment: @user4419802 How will you find that two values (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2) are equivalent if (for example) z1 != z2, but abs(z1-z2) < delta, where delta is the minimal tolerance factor for doubles?

Comment: @amit Let's take a (bad) example: hash = round(x+y+z) (I assume 3*fabs(delta) < 0.5). This function is (probably) bad only because of bad distribution. Yet, principally, it works: both values would go to the same chain, where we find them by linear search.

Comment: @user4419802 No, assume x1=x2=y1=y2=0, z1 = 0.5+delta/2, z2=0.5-delta/2. The two points will be splitted to two hash values. The probability of such thing to happen increases as you try to make your hash distribute better.

Comment: @amit: there are sometimes valid use cases for using hash table for floats. For example, if the float comes from the result of parsing rather than the result of calculation, a decent parser would always parse the same string to the same float, so no rounding errors would be possible. I don't know where the OP is getting his data from, so this has to be mentioned because exact search are often sufficient.

Comment: @amit OK, then let's add any value twice: to h(x-d,y-d,z-d) and to h(x+d,y+d,z+d) chains (if hashes are really different).

Comment: @user4419802 When you are starting to patch solutions it's usually a bad indication. I have no idea if the current patch will work or not, but as a rule of thumb, do not hash floating points. Some exceptions may be tolerable when coming from parsings (like LieRyan suggests), but if any calculation is involved - just don't, all the literature warns about it over and over again, probably for a good reason.

Comment: @amit To develop an instant solution is usually to produce a bug. We all need some time to do the things well. And 'patching', well, you may likewise call 'patching', for example, balanced trees, cause they are just 'patching' normal search-trees. The hash is more than just a single algorithm. We need 1) good distribution, 2) ability to find all candidate-buckets (given that, there would not be too many of them). And that's obviously a feasible task.

Comment: @user4419802 With all due respect, unless you can provide some hashing solution that is backed by literature for hashing triplets of doubles, I will not tolerate it in my code. I am not saying there is none, but that should be an integral part of any answer that suggests hashing.

Comment: @amit Sorry but I don't understand your reference to 'literature'. All 'the literature' is written by people. And we both are humans too. The only reasonable requirement is providing proof. And proving the things by yourself (without any literature) is perfectly legal.

Comment: @user4419802 'literature' as - something that was published in a paper, was peer reviewed by experts, and gained popularity due to it. If you think you have something new, publish it in one of the articles, and let it be peer reviewed.

Comment: @amit The topic of (ad hoc) hashing floating-point numbers is not so great to make an article of it.

Comment: @user: For a hash table to have reasonable performance, there has to be essentially no correlation between the hash values of similar inputs. This requirement is diametrically opposed to our requirement here that similar outputs are mapped to a small set of hash values. What you are trying to do looks much more like discretization to me.

Comment: @Hurkyl Here we take as the definition, that _all_ the inputs with a difference less than _delta_ are really the same (not just _similar_). Yes, it's a discretization, but PCs can only handle a discretization, so it's a necessary evil.

Comment: @user: It follows that all nearly all inputs with a difference less than twice delta are the same (because if `x` and `y` are the same and `y` and `z` are the same, then `x` and `z` are the same). And nearly all inputs with a difference less than thrice delta are the same... and so forth.

Comment: @Hurkyl It's a common problem with PC floating-point operations. Initially, we store them with a small rounding error. Next, as we proceed with calculations, those errors could become greater etc. The point is, we must provide both different initial storage and the 'stability' of calculations - that is, the rounding errors should not become too big too fast. So at the end, our results are still have _small_ errors, which we may neglect. This is the field of its own interest but I can't teach the college course in the comments.

Comment: @user: ... and the important property of a hash function is that values with small differences do not have correlated hash values, which contradicts our desire to neglect small errors. I'm not saying that one can't build a strategy involving transforming a `double` into a small set of things you *can* do exact matching on -- I'm saying that it's misleading and obfuscating (if not outright *wrong*) to describe it as hashing floating-point values.

Comment: @Hurkyl Again, for our purposes we treat these values not as 'having small differences' but as being the same. And same values must produce same hashes. I see no obfuscating here.

Comment: @user: Then all numbers map to the same hash value, by the argument I gave above. (I'm not being precise about the edge cases; e.g. if we fix `delta`, then numbers large enough that `x + delta == x` probably are allowed their own hash value)

Comment: @Hurkyl If you can't distinguish numbers you can't operate on them. If in the beginning you have the triplet (x-delta), x, (x+delta) then you don't know what x is equal to - either (x-delta) or (x+delta). Here the starting conditions are bad, not (any) algorithm.

Comment: @user: There are many, many more possible keys than those two that I'd want `x` to match when I do a lookup, such as `x` or `x + delta/2` or `x - 17*delta/256` or .... Also, the starting conditions are not bad -- they are what they are. What is bad is, for example, trying to apply an algorithm for searching for *exact* matches when your goal is to search for approximate matches.

Comment: @Hurkyl It is simply not safe to operate on floats when the real difference is near to precision. As errors propagate, just a couple of innocently-looking operations could break everything. It's not my wish but a standard safety-measure to assume that for all distinct input x, y holds that, say, fabs(x-y) > 10*delta. If not, the starting conditions are really wrong.

Comment: @user: I can't make any sense of your comment. In case we're talking past each other, I'll start over, from the point of the very first comment: when doing a lookup in a table of floating point values, you usually don't want an exact match: you instead want to find those `y` such that `abs(x-y) < threshold`. Consequently, doing lookups based on applying a hash function to `float` data is a bad idea, since those are based on finding exact matches.

Comment: @user4419802: What you have (incorrectly) called as delta is actually properly called [epsilon/rounding error](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon). The problem with discrete rounded hashing is that it puts floats into discrete buckets, which is not how [delta/margin of errors](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error) are usually handled when doing physical measurements in physical sciences. The delta/margin of error would maintain the property that the floats are fairly continuous around the magnitude of the delta, as long as the delta is much higher than the epsilon.

Comment: @user4419802: (cont.) Discrete rounded hashing doesn't satisfy that continuity requirement. The main advantage of discrete hashing though, is that it doesn't suffer from the Sorites paradox, which implies some nice properties like equality relations being transitive, but its rounding errors will only grow. Discrete rounded hashing can be suitable for purposes where physical accuracy isn't very important (e.g. games graphics). But if you need accurate physical calculations, you must use the delta/margin of error calculations to ensure that rounding errors do not grow uncontrollably.

Comment: @Hurkyl Let's build an example. For simplicity I take one-dimensional array of floats, search precision 0.01 and H(n) - some 'good' integer hash. Let h1(x) = H(ceil(100*x)) and h2(x) = H(floor(100*x)). Then for any given x, I add x to both h1(x) and h2(x) buckets. To check some y against hash-table I do linear searching in h1(y) and h2(y) buckets. So what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably come as bad news for you, but I think the best fit for your purpose is the [**k-d tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), and it is not implemented in the standard library.

This data structure allows you to search the closest neighbor to any given point in multi-dimensional space (3d space in your case). This will guarantee tolerance for rounding errors that are most likely to occur when dealing with floating-point keys.

However, this DS is very popular and I am sure you will be able to find an online implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **OcTree** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree). It would be faster and more convenient than any container in std based on binary tree. Also you would not worry about index or hash functions. However it will take more memory. It can be used even for NN(Nearest Neighbors) search. Another option is the **Kd-tree** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). Both are not part of STD. KdTree needs less memory than OcTree and sometimes is even faster. You should be able to find good C++ implementations of OcTree or KdTree with google.